# Ace editor: how to implement highlighter into nested blocks?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I have custom mode and highlighter for this. I want to embed Markdown highlighter into my highlighter based on simple Text highlighter. Here is my highlighter code:

```
ace.define("ace/mode/brainch_highlight_rules", (acequire, exports, module) => {
  const oop = acequire("ace/lib/oop");

  const BaseTextHighlightRules = acequire("ace/mode/text_highlight_rules").TextHighlightRules;
  const MarkdownHighlightRules = acequire("ace/mode/markdown_highlight_rules").MarkdownHighlightRules;

  const BrainchMarkdownHighlightRules = function() {
    MarkdownHighlightRules.call(this);

    this.$rules.start.unshift({
      token: "meta.username",
      regex: "@[A-Za-z_]+",
      next: "start"
    });

    this.normalizeRules();
  };
  oop.inherits(BrainchMarkdownHighlightRules, MarkdownHighlightRules);

  const BrainchBlocksHighlightRules = function() {
    BaseTextHighlightRules.call(this);

    this.$rules.start.unshift({
      token: "meta.block.block_task",
      regex: "^\\-",
      next: "brainch-start"
    }, {
      token: "meta.block.block_note",
      regex: "^[^\\-]",
      next: "brainch-start"
    });

    this.embedRules(BrainchMarkdownHighlightRules, "brainch-", [{
      regex: "$", onMatch: function(val, state, stack) {
        this.next = "start";
        return "meta.block";
      }
    }], ["start"]);

    this.normalizeRules();
  }
  oop.inherits(BrainchBlocksHighlightRules, BaseTextHighlightRules);

  exports.BrainchHighlightRules = BrainchBlocksHighlightRules;
});
```

I want to define blocks format by two rules:

1. If text in block starts with `-` then apply styles from CSS `block_task` class.
2. Else format block as `block_note` class.

Also I want to format inner text with Markdown and my custom rules.

How can I do this?

Comment: In other word, I want to next HTML as result:

`- This is @username _in_ text` parsed to `<span class="block_task">- This is <span class="username">@username</span> <span class="emphasis">_in_</span> text</span>`